# SciFi episode where one of the crew members becomes a monster

Tags: story-identification

I remember seeing a SciFi episode where one of the crew members on a spaceship becomes a monster; he realizes that but can't do anything about it. He got outside onto a planet and was hunted down and, I think, subsequently healed, when he got his original form back.

It must have been end of the seventies. Could also have been a repeat.

Is there a classic Star Trek episode that would fit?

Comment: This seems entirely too generic to identify, I'm pretty sure every long running scifi/fantasy series has done a variant of such a plot. The only significant narrowing characteristic is that he is able to leave the ship and get on a planet.

Comment: When you say *every* series could you pinpoint the one from Star Trek TOS? Thank you

Comment: There really isn't an episode of TOS that fits your description, so it must have been one of the other series or else some other show.

Comment: In a comment on Tango's answer, you say that there was no TNG when you saw this particular episode. Maybe if you estimated the year it was on, then it would help. Also, when I see SciFi, I assume it's the cable channel, but it could also mean generic science fiction. You might want to edit the question to clarify these points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure you're not talking about ["Identity Crisis"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_Crisis_%28Star_Trek%3a_The_Next_Generation%29) from *Star Trek: The Next Generation*?  In that episode, Geordi is infected by an alien parasite that alters his DNA and changes him into a creature that needs to return to its home planet.  He can find out something about what's happening, but not in time to stop his mutation.  Of course, the Enterprise crew figures it all out and undoes the mutation to his DNA so he is back to normal in time for the next week's episode.

Comment: I am pretty sure because at that time when I saw the other episode there was no TNG yet...

Comment: Are you sure it was a continuing series, like Trek or Space: 199 or something and not an anthology like Twilight Zone or Outer Limits?  Also, if you remember about when it happened, that might help.

Comment: Yes, it was definitely a continuing series and I thought that it was ST:TOS but nobody seems to remember this episode there.

Comment: Can you describe the planet or the monster?  Or about when it aired?

Comment: Must have been in the seventies and the monster was like massive rock, like a Hulk not green though, but more brownish or greyish.

Comment: There was an episode of Space:1999 where Maya, the metamorph, was ill and shape changed into something that could live in the vacuum and went out onto the Moon (which, in your memory, could seem like another planet) and they had to get her back in an hour, because that's the longest she could hold her shape.  Was it on US TV or from the US?  Or from somewhere else?

Comment: It was in Germany, but most series here are from the US (with a certain time lag). Could you say which episode of Space:1999 it was?

Comment: I just checked when it was aired in Germany - and it matches, perhaps we are on the right track here...

Comment: It was "Space Warp."  Some of these summaries are slow links: <http://space1999.epguides.info/?ID=809&ComingFrom=343A3337711304060A11021602465053525D080D0E00025D5C4E05020310>, <http://www.space1999.net/catacombs/main/epguide/t40sw.html>

Comment: There was an episode of Star Trek TOS in which an alien monster that was essentially a rock/magma monster made Kirk, Spock and recreations of Abraham Lincoln and Surak fight for their lives and classic battle of good vs evil.  But that's as close to that as I can recall.

Answer (score 3):

This also sounds like an episode from Stargate SG-1 from Season 2 called *Bane*. SG-1 travels to a planet that is apparently devoid of all visible and detectable life forms. Soon they discover the planet is swarming with bugs one of which stings Teal'c before being shot by Colonel O'Neill. When SG-1 arrives home Teal'c begins going through a process where his DNA is being re-written the end result being him a host for more of the bugs in larval form. He is cured by the end of the episode but not before going through excruciating pain etc.

Comment: Thank you. I guess the problem is that this episode was much later.

Comment: Oh I know, just saying that's what it sounds like :P